# Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Tags: java, excepciones, selenium, test-ng

Tengo la siguiente excepción: como podría resolverla

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

el código que estoy ejecutando es este:

```
package globalTest;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pages.contactUsPage;
import pages.fiftyPage;
import pages.footerPage;
import pages.footerProjectsPage;
import pages.hamburgerMenu;

public class suite {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() {
    // driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Primera prueba");
}

@AfterClass
public void afterClass() {
    driver.quit();
    System.out.println("finaliza");
}

@Test
public void hamburguer() {
    driver.get(URL);
    hamburgerMenu hamburguer= new hamburgerMenu(driver);
}

@Test(priority = 1, enabled = true, invocationCount = 2)
public void contactUs() {
    driver.get(URL);

    contactUsPage contact = new contactUsPage(driver);
    contact.contact();
    contact.name();
    contact.email();
    contact.subject();
    contact.message();
    contact.send();

}

@Test(priority = 2, enabled = true)
public void contactUs2() {
    driver.get(URL);

    contactUsPage contact = new contactUsPage(driver);
    contact.email();

}

@Test(priority = 3, enabled = true)
public void fiftyPage() {
    driver.get(URL);

    fiftyPage fiftypage = new fiftyPage(driver);
    fiftypage.ourwork();
    fiftypage.fifty();



}

@Test
public void footerpageemail() {
    driver.get(URL);
    footerPage footer = new footerPage(driver);

    footer.hamburguer();
    footer.ourwork();
    footer.fifty();
    footer.up();
    footer.contacemail();

}

@Test
public void footerpagefacebook() {
    driver.get(URL);
    footerPage footer = new footerPage(driver);

    footer.hamburguer();
    footer.ourwork();
    footer.fifty();
    footer.facebook();

}

@Test
public void footerpagelinkendlin() {
    driver.get(URL);
    footerPage footer = new footerPage(driver);

    footer.hamburguer();
    footer.ourwork();
    footer.fifty();
    footer.linkendlin();

}

@Test
public void footerprojectspage() {     
    driver.get(URL);
    footerProjectsPage footerproject = new footerProjectsPage(driver);

    footerproject.hamburguer();
    footerproject.ourwork();
    footerproject.fifty();
    footerproject.mozidorigth();
    footerproject.otteright();
    footerproject.fiftyright();
    footerproject.otteleft();
    footerproject.mozidoleft();
    footerproject.fiftyleft();



}
```

}

Comment: Podrias mostrar el codigo actual que produce este problema, ademas que librerias usas, probablemente se deba no se esta importanto bien una clase al classpath

Comment: Hola, selenium-java-2.31.0, selenium-server-standalone-2.7.0.patched, httpclient-4.1.1, testng-6.9.9

Comment: @Laura asegura tener la clase ParameterException dentro de : com/beust/jcommander/

Comment: Creo que te falta la libreria jcommander, en [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander)

Answer (score 1):

Laura revisa el error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException

**Significa que esta clase, no se encuentra en tu proyecto o el paquete para acceder a ella es diferente.**

Existe alguna clase en tu proyecto que esta tratando de usar la clase `ParameterException` pero no la encuentra.

Como indica @jasilva al parecer la clase `ParameterException` pertenece a  la librería [jcommander](http://jcommander.org/) la cual al parecer no se encuentra, si revisamos la documentación esta es la forma de agregarla mediante Maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
  <version>1.48</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Y que sucede si no estoy usando maven? que hago :(

Comment: Toca descargar el jar a mano.

Answer (score 0):

Lo típico es que al obtener Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError el problema se deba a que el classpath está mal y/o no se encuentra la clase como se comenta, pero tras pasar por esta pregunta y saber que en mi caso no se debía a eso encontré luego esta otra posibilidad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381202/a-jni-error-has-occurred-please-check-your-installation-and-try-again-in-eclips (en resumen, que haya un conflicto de versiones de JDK y JRE).